# What is the list of all Android Init Language 'triggers'?

Tags: android, triggers, init

In /init.rc and the other Android Init Language '.rc' files, there can be 'actions' sections that start: 'on ' to execute a sequence of commands when an event occurs in the init process.  What is the list of all 'triggers'?  There seem to see some specific keyword triggers, like 'boot', 'init', 'fs', 'early-init' and 'post-fs-data'.  Is this a complete list of these?  In the code somewhere?  (In addition to the keyword triggers there are some expression triggers, see below.)

Some keyword triggers I've seen, it would be nice to know when and why they are called:

```
boot
early-init
init
fs
post-fs-data
charger
nonencrypted
```

In addition to keywords, exmaples of expressions include:

```
property:ro.factory.tool=1     -- when a property is set to a value
device-added-<path>  -- Triggered when a node is added when the equipment
device-removed-<path>  -- When the device is removed to add nodes
service-exited-<name>
```

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Please refer the README file from system/core/init folder of AOSP code. You can find all the details about android init here.

Link for Android O OS README file : http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/system/core/init/README.md

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, the triggers are not listed in the documentation

Answer (score 25):

You can also list it on connected phone / emulator with adb:

```
$ adb shell dmesg | grep "processing action"
[    4.376074] init: processing action 0x35480 (init)
[    4.440537] init: processing action 0x38c58 (init)
[    4.450009] init: processing action 0x35708 (early-fs)
[    5.531812] init: processing action 0x39c38 (console_init)
[    5.575831] init: processing action 0x2de70 (fs)
[    5.597799] init: processing action 0x35890 (fs)
[    7.089157] init: processing action 0x2df58 (post-fs)
[    7.091550] init: processing action 0x38cb8 (post-fs)
[    7.091818] init: processing action 0x2e288 (post-fs-data)
[    7.100189] init: processing action 0x39c80 (property_service_init)
[    7.110080] init: processing action 0x39cc8 (signal_init)
[    7.110177] init: processing action 0x39d10 (check_startup)
[    7.110248] init: processing action 0x2ea18 (boot)
[    7.126205] init: processing action 0x397e0 (boot)
[    8.183090] init: processing action 0x39d58 (queue_property_triggers)
[    8.183232] init: processing action 0x2f8f8 (nonencrypted)
[    8.183810] init: processing action 0x2fd98 (property:ro.debuggable=1)
[    8.184463] init: processing action 0x328f8 (property:sys.usb.config=none)
[   14.438626] init: processing action 0x2ffd0 (property:sys.sensors=1)
[   28.192393] init: processing action 0x31860 (property:sys.boot_completed=1)
```

Answer (score 12):

*Note: at the time of writing, all links point to AOSP android-5.1.1_r18*

Triggers can be defined by developers (device maintainers), so we cannot hope to find a *complete* list. But, presuming you are most interested in those included in AOSP by default, here's the flow:

Actions processed in [platform/system/core/init/init.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-5.1.1_r18/init/init.c) via `action_for_each_trigger()`:

1. `early-init`
2. `init`
3. `charger` *or* `late-init`

If `charger` is the last trigger encountered, then this is the end of the AOSP defined list. Manufacturers can supplement the subsequent actions for offmode charging from here.

If `late-init` is the last trigger encountered, then the default init.rc included in Android ([platform/system/core/rootdir/init.rc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-5.1.1_r18/rootdir/init.rc#168)) starts running the following triggers:

```
# Mount filesystems and start core system services.
on late-init
    trigger early-fs
    trigger fs
    trigger post-fs
    trigger post-fs-data

    # Load properties from /system/ + /factory after fs mount. Place
    # this in another action so that the load will be scheduled after the prior
    # issued fs triggers have completed.
    trigger load_all_props_action

    # Remove a file to wake up anything waiting for firmware.
    trigger firmware_mounts_complete

    trigger early-boot
    trigger boot
```

Comment: For [current master (android > 6)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/init.cpp) it's in method `am.QueueEventTrigger()` (init is again rewritten to C++).

Answer (score 3):

The most effective way to find all of these standard triggers is to perform a grep for the word "trigger" on all of the `*.rc` files in the [`system/core/rootdir` directory](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/rootdir/).

```
grep trigger rootdir/*
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few keywords that everyone knows, but if you want to see a list of properties that are being set (and others that are defaulted to) try this adb command:

```
$ adb shell getprop
[alsa.mixer.capture.headset]: [Capture]
[alsa.mixer.capture.master]: [Capture]
[alsa.mixer.playback.headset]: [Headphone]
[alsa.mixer.playback.master]: [Playback]
[alsa.mixer.playback.speaker]: [Playback]
[back_camera_name]: [ov5640_mipi]
[back_camera_orient]: [0]
[camera.disable_zsl_mode]: [1]
[dalvik.vm.dexopt-flags]: [m=y]
[dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.heapmaxfree]: [8m]
[dalvik.vm.heapminfree]: [512k]
[dalvik.vm.heapsize]: [384m]
[dalvik.vm.heapstartsize]: [8m]
[dalvik.vm.heaptargetutilization]: [0.75]
[dalvik.vm.jniopts]: [warnonly]
[dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file]: [/data/anr/traces.txt]
[debug.egl.hw]: [1]
[debug.force_rtl]: [0]
[debug.sf.enable_hgl]: [1]
[debug.sf.showfps]: [0]
[dev.bootcomplete]: [1]
[dhcp.eth0.result]: [failed]
[front_camera_name]: [ov5642_camera,ov5640_camera]
[front_camera_orient]: [0]
[gsm.current.phone-type]: [1]
[gsm.network.type]: [Unknown]
[gsm.operator.alpha]: []
[gsm.operator.iso-country]: []
[gsm.operator.isroaming]: [false]
[gsm.operator.numeric]: []
[gsm.ril.delay]: [15]
[gsm.sim.state]: [NOT_READY]
[hwc.enable_dither]: [1]
[hwc.stretch.filter]: [1]
[init.svc.adbd]: [running]
[init.svc.bootanim]: [stopped]
[init.svc.console]: [running]
[init.svc.debuggerd]: [running]
[init.svc.dhcpcd_eth0]: [stopped]
[init.svc.drm]: [running]
[init.svc.fuse_extsd]: [running]
[init.svc.healthd]: [running]
[init.svc.installd]: [running]
[init.svc.keystore]: [running]
[init.svc.media]: [running]
[init.svc.netd]: [running]
[init.svc.sdcard]: [running]
[init.svc.servicemanager]: [running]
[init.svc.surfaceflinger]: [running]
[init.svc.ueventd]: [running]
[init.svc.uim]: [stopped]
[init.svc.vold]: [running]
[init.svc.wifi_mac]: [stopped]
[init.svc.zygote]: [running]
[media.omxgm.enable-player]: [1]
[media.omxgm.enable-record]: [1]
[media.omxgm.enable-scan]: [1]
[net.bt.name]: [Android]
[net.change]: [net.qtaguid_enabled]
[net.hostname]: [android-c49d34ff0fbd9f6]
[net.qtaguid_enabled]: [1]
[net.tcp.buffersize.default]: [4096,87380,110208,4096,16384,110208]
[net.tcp.buffersize.edge]: [4093,26280,35040,4096,16384,35040]
[net.tcp.buffersize.ethernet]: [524288,2097152,4194304,524288,2097152,4194304]
[net.tcp.buffersize.evdo]: [4094,87380,262144,4096,16384,262144]
[net.tcp.buffersize.gprs]: [4092,8760,11680,4096,8760,11680]
[net.tcp.buffersize.hsdpa]: [4094,87380,262144,4096,16384,262144]
[net.tcp.buffersize.hspa]: [4094,87380,262144,4096,16384,262144]
[net.tcp.buffersize.hspap]: [4094,87380,1220608,4096,16384,1220608]
[net.tcp.buffersize.hsupa]: [4094,87380,262144,4096,16384,262144]
[net.tcp.buffersize.lte]: [524288,1048576,2097152,262144,524288,1048576]
[net.tcp.buffersize.umts]: [4094,87380,110208,4096,16384,110208]
[net.tcp.buffersize.wifi]: [524288,1048576,2097152,262144,524288,1048576]
[persist.service.bdroid.bdaddr]: [22:22:12:0c:fb:0d]
[persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib]: [libdvm.so]
[persist.sys.profiler_ms]: [0]
[persist.sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[qemu.hw.mainkeys]: [1]
[ro.FSL_AAC_PARSER]: [1]
[ro.FSL_ASF_PARSER]: [0]
[ro.FSL_AVI_PARSER]: [1]
[ro.FSL_FLAC_PARSER]: [1]
[ro.FSL_FLV_PARSER]: [1]
[ro.FSL_MKV_PARSER]: [1]
[ro.FSL_MPG2_PARSER]: [1]
[ro.FSL_REAL_PARSER]: [0]
[ro.adb.secure]: [1]
[ro.allow.mock.location]: [1]
[ro.baseband]: [unknown]
[ro.board.platform]: [imx6]
[ro.boot.bootdev]: [mmcblk3]
[ro.boot.hardware]: [freescale]
[ro.boot.serialno]: [19b80271c6]
[ro.bootloader]: [unknown]
[ro.bootmode]: [unknown]
[ro.build.characteristics]: [tablet]
[ro.build.date.utc]: [1484264053]
[ro.build.date]: [Thu Jan 12 17:34:13 CST 2017]
[ro.build.description]: [nitrogen6x-eng 4.4.3 2.0.1-ga 20160816 dev-keys]
[ro.build.display.id]: [nitrogen6x-eng 4.4.3 2.0.1-ga 20160816 dev-keys]
[ro.build.fingerprint]: [boundary/nitrogen6x/nitrogen6x:4.4.3/2.0.1-ga/20160816:eng/dev-keys]
[ro.build.host]: [fbd-HP-ZBook-15]
[ro.build.id]: [2.0.1-ga]
[ro.build.product]: [nitrogen6x]
[ro.build.tags]: [dev-keys]
[ro.build.type]: [eng]
[ro.build.user]: [fbd]
[ro.build.version.codename]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.incremental]: [20160816]
[ro.build.version.release]: [4.4.3]
[ro.build.version.sdk]: [19]
[ro.carrier]: [unknown]
[ro.config.alarm_alert]: [Alarm_Classic.ogg]
[ro.config.notification_sound]: [OnTheHunt.ogg]
[ro.crypto.state]: [unencrypted]
[ro.debuggable]: [1]
[ro.factorytest]: [0]
[ro.hardware]: [freescale]
[ro.kernel.android.checkjni]: [1]
[ro.opengles.version]: [196608]
[ro.product.board]: []
[ro.product.brand]: [boundary]
[ro.product.cpu.abi2]: [armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [armeabi-v7a]
[ro.product.device]: [nitrogen6x]
[ro.product.locale.language]: [en]
[ro.product.locale.region]: [US]
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [boundary]
[ro.product.model]: [NITROGEN6X]
[ro.product.name]: [nitrogen6x]
[ro.revision]: [405522]
[ro.ril.wake_lock_timeout]: [300]
[ro.runtime.firstboot]: [582594834]
[ro.secure]: [0]
[ro.serialno]: [19b80271c6]
[ro.sf.hwrotation]: [0]
[ro.sf.lcd_density]: [160]
[ro.tether.denied]: [false]
[ro.wifi.channels]: []
[ro.zygote.disable_gl_preload]: [true]
[rw.VIDEO_RENDER_NAME]: [video_render.surface]
[service.bootanim.exit]: [1]
[sys.boot_completed]: [1]
[sys.emulated.battery]: [1]
[sys.interactive]: [active]
[sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes]: [12000]
[sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[sys.usb.state]: [mtp,adb]
[system_init.startsurfaceflinger]: [0]
[vold.post_fs_data_done]: [1]
[wifi.ap.interface]: [wlan0]
[wifi.interface]: [wlan0]
[wlan.interface]: [wlan0]
```

I'm running Android 4.4.2 on Boundary Devices' Sabrelite board. See link for the getprop adb command [here](http://osxr.org:8080/android/source/frameworks/compile/libbcc/gdb_plugin/android-commands.py#0276). See this [blog](http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-property-system.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is late, but in case if someone is still facing the problem I decided to answer it.
**On Early Init-**
Set init and its forked children's oom_adj
Set the security context for all the init process.
**on init-**
setup the global environment 
Create mounting points
**on fs-**
mount mtd partitions
**on post-fs-**
change the permission of system directories
**on post-fs-data-**
change the permission of /data folders and subfolders
**on boot -**
basic network init, Memory management 
**service servicemanager**
start system manager to manage all native services like location, audio, shared preferences etc.
**service zygote-**
start zygote as an app_process

The source for the above information is http://www.onsandroid.com/2014/10/in-depth-android-boot-sequence-process.html